# Package 'netcat' has no installation candidate Ubuntu 22.10 Kinetic Redmail

Tags: ubuntu, apt, apt-get, netcat, iredmail

When I try to install Redmail I get the error:

```
Package netcat is a virtual package provided by:
  netcat-traditional 1.10-47
  netcat-openbsd 1.218-5ubuntu1

E: Package 'netcat' has no installation candidate
<< ERROR >> Installation failed, please check the terminal output.
<< ERROR >> If you're not sure what the problem is, try to get help in iRedMail
<< ERROR >> forum: https://forum.iredmail.org/
```

I don't know what to do.

Ubuntu details:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.10
Release:        22.10
Codename:       kinetic
```

I would really appreciate some help. Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I believe iRedMail was meant to be installed on 22.04 LTS, but I was able to do the following to make it work on 22.10:

Open the file /functions/packages.sh

Look for the line that references netcat

Change it to netcat-traditional